# Bash Script - No file exist in ~/.ssh/

Tags: linux, bash, quoting, tilde-expansion

I'm trying to copy a file from: ~/.ssh/
but everytime I run the script it keeps saying

```
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/greenwich $ ./copybash.sh
cat: ~/.ssh/testfilegen2.log: No such file or directory
```

copybash.sh

```
!/bin/bash
sourceFile="~/.ssh/testfilegen2.log"
targetFile="/etc/network/interfaces2"
sudo cat "$sourceFile" > "$targetFile"
sudo service networking restart
```

Any Suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: You really need to provide more information, especially the code inside that `copybash.sh` script.

Comment: @Fred included copybash.sh code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unquote the tilde in the assignment to `sourceFile` so that it expands properly. Tilde expansion does not occur on parameter expansion.

```
sourceFile=~/".ssh/testfilegen2.log"
```

(In this case, no quotes would be necessary at all, but just to demonstrate that the `~` and the following `/` are the only things that need to remain unquoted for tilde expansion to occur.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this snippet code:

```
#!/bin/bash
v1=~/'file1.txt'
v2=~/'file2.txt'
echo 'Hi!' > $v1 
cat $v1 > $v2
cat $v2

$ script.sh
Hi!
```

The documentation is in the section "Tilde Expansion"
of the "[General Commands Manual BASH](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/bash/bash.1.en.html)".